# using one input file with two different form

Tags: php, html, forms

Is there a way to using a input file with two different form?

I need only one input file and have to post this file to .php page depending of user selection.

Thanks.

```
<label for="file">Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<form action="c.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="C">
</form>
<form action="d.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="D">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect to page cd.php which includes c.php or d.php depending on the value C or D

Comment: you mean i need to create a cd.php file which only have `<?php if(..)include 'c.php';  else include 'd.php';?>` ?  But i have to use two button

Comment: Not necessarily. The "value=D" can selected in another input. For instance have two radiobuttons in your form where the user selects the value and then only one button.

Also, depending on the amount of code in your c.php and d.php and the rest of your application, it may be possible to join them in one file and have an if/else clause for the different actions.